# scala.sys.process: == doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, unit-testing, process

I've recently discover the scala.sys.process and began to play with it.

I'm trying to write a parser for a bash file, and I found a strange behavior of the == method while writing unit tests.
(I know I could just directly run the bash file, but see this as an exercise).

```
import scala.sys.process._

def processFromFile(file: String) = {
    val in = Source.fromFile(file)
    val lines = in.getLines
    val commands = lines filterNot(_.startsWith("#"))

    def toProcessBuilder(commands: List[String]): ProcessBuilder = commands match {
        case a :: b :: l => a ### toProcessBuilder(b :: l)
        case a :: Nil => a
        case Nil => ""
    }

    toProcessBuilder(commands.toList)
}
```

and here is my unit test :

```
test("the process parser works correctly") {
    val process = "ls" ### "git log"
    val processLoaded = Experiment.processFromFile("experiments/test.sh")
    assert(process == processLoaded)
}
```

The "test.sh" file contains only :

```
#test
ls
git log
```

But the unit test fail with the following code :

```
[info] - the process parser works correctly *** FAILED ***
[info]   ( [ls] ### [git, log] )  did not equal  ( [ls] ### [git, log] )
```

For me it's look like process and processLoaded are equals, and if I compare the _.toString of both the test is accepted.

So what is happening here, why can't scala compare this two objects correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

What equality means for a `ProcessBuilder` (which by the way isn't a concrete class but an interface) is probably not that straight forward even if it in your case might seem like it should be the same command with the same operations.

The implementations you get back does not have a custom equals/hashcode and will therefore inherit the default object equals which compares based on object identity. This means only the same instance will be equal with itself.

I would create a special comparator/matcher for the test framework that matches the list of commands inside the ProcessBuilder (for example like you say by `toString`:ing it)